# Find equation to fit data with plateau

Tags: exponential-function, data-analysis

I have a dataset with X and Y values. I would like to fit the data which plateaus at a certain value Y (want to extract the Y where it plateaus).

The data includes (0 0) and for increasing x (no limit) the Y values do not increase beyond a certain Y value.

[Plateau for distance vs square root of time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP4SY.png)

[Plateau for distance vs time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHE3U.png)

What would be the (most suitable) fitting function?

Comment: [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you provide more detail - perhaps a graph of your data - you are more likely to get an answer. In the meanwhile look into logistic curves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: Thank you @EthanBolker, I just added some graphs.

Answer (score 3):

You can fit 
$$
y = M(1- e^{-ax})
$$
where $M$ is the maximum at which the plateau ends up and $a$ governs how fast it gets there.

You can probably get Excel to find the best values of $M$ and $a$, or just play until the graph looks right.

Comment: Is that the most appropriate equation for such? It seems there are a variety of fitting functions out there and I am wondering how to choose the most suitable for such a plateau?

Comment: eg. http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_11.html